# column {table_name} of relation {table_name} does not exist SQL state: 42703

Tags: postgresql, table, update

I am getting an error while running an update query with table name specified along with column name:

```
UPDATE Temp SET Temp.Id='234',Temp.Name='Test'WHERE Id='245'
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR:  column "temp" of relation "temp" does not exist
LINE 1:      UPDATE Temp SET Temp.Id='23...
                               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "temp" of relation "temp" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 24
```

Answer (score 15):

You cannot (and need not) use table aliases (or tablename qualified column names) in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE`.  This even makes sense, as you can only update a single table in a single `UPDATE`, so there is no ambiguity in column names there.

Fortunately, the ever helpful documentation [explicitly mentions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) your case:

> **column_name**
>
> The name of a column in the table named by `table_name`. The column name can be qualified with a subfield name or array subscript,
>   if needed. Do not include the table's name in the specification of a
>   target column — for example, `UPDATE tab SET tab.col = 1` is invalid.

So, the solution is to simply remove `temp.` from the `SET` clause:

```
UPDATE temp SET id = '234', name = 'Test' WHERE id = '245'
```

**Notes:**

- Are you really storing numbers as text?  If yes, why?  It is usually a recipe for disaster.  For example, how do you prevent something like `'mkjcvnd7y78r3tgbhvcjh'` entering your `id` column?
- The way you are using object names starting with capital letters is confusing.  Without double-quoting its name, your table in reality is called `temp` as opposed to `Temp`.  Using it the latter way may decrease readability (depending on your preferences and habits, of course).

Answer (score 1):

What would happen in the case of doing an update for 2 tables that have the same field name?

```
update car c, airplane a
set c.nr_rute = 1
set a.nr_rute = 1
```

Comment: That statement is simply not a valid standard SQL statement, nor a valid PostgreSQL statment. Your database will complain.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/177020)